# Integrating a list of values in Python

Tags: python, list, scipy, numerical-integration, integral

I have a list of data, which represents acceleration. For simplicity, let's say this list is:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to integrate each value in this list twice (double integration) so I can retrieve information about location.

Quick reminder: position, velocity, and acceleration are related. You can find acceleration by taking the derivative twice. Or, you can take the integral twice if you start with acceleration.

I cannot really change the data I am working with. I have floating point values stored in a list coming from my accelerometer. I also understand that usually, integration requires a function to be defined, typically with a variable that can be integrated over an interval.

I have tried using the library:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
```

and have attempted using the `.quad` method, but I am yielding errors.

I would love any tips, ideas, or links to resources that could help.

[Github repo](https://github.com/andrejandre/Accelerometer-Algorithms/blob/master/FirstAlgorithm.py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.cumtrapz` method. `cumtrapz(X)` computes the approximate cumulative integral of X via the trapezoidal method with unit spacing.

```
import scipy.integrate as it
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
velocity = it.cumtrapz(X,initial=0)
location = it.cumtrapz(velocity,initial=0)
print 'velocity: ', velocity
print 'location: ', location
```

Output:

```
velocity:  [  0.    1.5   4.    7.5  12. ]
location:  [  0.     0.75   3.5    9.25  19.  ]
```

Note if your have the time vector `t` corresponding to acceleration vector, you need to use `cumtrapz(X,t)`. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html) is the reference for method `cumtrapz`.

Comment: I have confirmed that this method works, I am able to integrate and return a velocity value. However, do I need to use the time vector `t` for the second integration, when I am calculating location?

I attempted to do so, but it yields errors regarding the size of 'x' and 'y'. Can I perform the second integration as:

    `cumtrapz(X_Velocity, initial = 0)` ?

It returns values, but I guess the only way to find out is to plot and see if I am reproducing the correct trajectories.

Comment: @Dr.Dre If you didn't use time vector `t`, it will use `t=[1,2,3,4,5]` in default. If you need to specify `t`, make sure it is the same size as `X`.

Comment: If I plot the values: How can I get the x-axis to be multiplied by 0.01?

Comment: What is if there are negative values in the values? For example X = [1, -2, 3, -2, 4, -3]

Comment: what a function name tho...

Answer (score -1):

You just need to sum in a simple for loop.

dv = a*dt

dx = 0.5*a*dt^2

Note - I wrote this code w/o checking it, so there may be some syntax errors

```
v = [0]  # or whatever you initial velocity is
x = [0]  # or whatever you initial location is
dt = 1.0 # or your time interval

for a in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    v.append(v[-1] + a*dt)
    x.append(x[-1] + 0.5*a*dt**2)
print(v)
print(x)
```