# Integration of a function with discrete values

Tags: python, list, numpy, integration, numeric

I want to do a integration without knowing the functional equation f(x). I also have only discrete values, which Python has connected by a plot. This one looks like this:

[image]

This is the code with the calculation for it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import loaddataa as ld

# Loading of the values
dataListStride = ld.loadData("../Projektpraktikum Binder/Data/1 Fabienne/Test1/left foot/50cm")
indexStrideData = 0 
strideData = dataListStride[indexStrideData]

#%%Calculation of the horizontal acceleration

def horizontal(yAngle, yAcceleration, xAcceleration):
     a = ((m.cos(m.radians(yAngle)))*yAcceleration)-((m.sin(m.radians(yAngle)))*xAcceleration)
     return a

resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    resultsHorizontal.append(horizontal(strideData_yAngle, strideData_yAcceleration, strideData_xAcceleration))

resultsHorizontal.insert(0, 0)

print("The values are: " +str(resultsHorizontal))

print("There are " +str(len(resultsHorizontal)) + " values.")

#x-axis "convert" into time: 100 Hertz makes 0.01 seconds

scale_factor = 0.01 
x_values = np.arange(len(resultsHorizontal)) * scale_factor
plt.plot(x_values, resultsHorizontal)
```

After the calculation I get a list of these values (which were shown and plotted in the diagram above):

[image]

**Note about the code:**
The code works as follows: By using loaddataa.py a csv file is reading in. Then the formula for the calculation of the horizontal acceleration is defined, which is represented in `def horizontal(yAngle,yAcceleration, xAcceleration)`. In the for loop, the previously determined list is run through line by line. Columns 2, 4 and 5 of the CSV file are used here. Then a 0 is added to the beginning of the resulting list of values. This is important to perform the integration from 0 to the end.

Now I want to integrate this function (which is represented in the plot at the top) with these values (which can be seen in the image after the code) after the calculation.

Is there a way to implement this? If so, how and what would the plot look like? Maybe there is the opportunity to do this with a trapeze integration? Thanks for helping me!

*At the end of my task I want to do a double integration with the acceleration values to get the path length. The first (trapezoidal) integration of the acceleration should represent the velocity and the second (trapezoidal) integration the path length (location). The x-axis should remain as it is.*

What I just noticed are the negative values. Theoretically the integration should always result in positive values, right? Because there are no negative areas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating a list of values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026955/integrating-a-list-of-values-in-python)

Comment: No not really. Could you please help me?